# rails add a where not in other table constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables

questions (here are all questions in)
inquiries (here I store the answers like this)
(id,question_ID,membership_ID,correct,wrong) ...

Now I want to add a NOT IN to my query to only get the questions which are not answered yet

now it looks like this:

```
lesson.questions.limit(limit)
```

can I add here a where statement with a NOT IN?

Thanks

UPDATE TABLEs

Question
[image]

Inquiries
[image]

Normal SQL could look like this:

```
select * 
from question
where question.id NOT IN(select inquires.question_id
from inquires
where inquires.membership_id = membership.id)
```

Comment: What is `lesson`?

Comment: questions belong to a lesson

Comment: added some information above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lesson.questions.joins(:answers).where(:answers => { :id => nil })
```

Comment: I tried it this way, but does not work: lesson.questions.joins(:inquiries).where(:inquiries => { :question_id => nil }).limit(limit)

Comment: `lesson.questions.joins(:inquiries).where(inquiries: { id: nil }).limit(limit)`
Use `id` not `question_id`

Comment: why not question id?, inquiries has an own id, the membership_id and the question_id

The connection to the membership ID is missing as well

Comment: Added the both tables above. I want all Questions which do not have a combination with membership ID in inquries. 

I have the Membership ID and want to prove if the user has already answerd a question

Comment: any idea how to achieve this?